# Resharper Code Cleanup Templates

Tags: resharper, resharper-10.0

Is there a way to add custom templates for code cleanup in ReSharper?

For Example, I want to remove using() statement in file in all methods.

Comment: Using [statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) or [directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) ? I really think you mean directives, don't you?

Comment: using statement 
Ex:  using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = impersonatedUser.Impersonate())

Comment: Why would you want to remove using statements?

Comment: i dont need to use them and there are lot of places to remove, so checking to see if i can write a template in resharper.

Comment: Honestly, I believe that's a bad idea... Either remove the `IDisposable` interface from the class, or keep the proper `using` statement.